# Disable all MediaWiki special pages for a group of users

Tags: mediawiki

I am looking to remove all access to SpecialPages for a new group called "Clients". Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#Clients group
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['userrights'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['edit'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['delete'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['upload'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['move'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['createtalk'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['createaccount'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['writeapi'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['createpage'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['sendemail'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['Clients']['editinterface'] = true;
```

Comment: Hi Kilmo, Did you got any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension [Lockdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockdown) will do that for you. Add the extension, and then do something like this:

```
$wgSpecialPageLockdown['Statistics'] = array('sysop');
$wgSpecialPageLockdown['Version'] = array('sysop');
$wgSpecialPageLockdown['Export'] = array('sysop');
...
```

This will be a long list, and it will change a bit from version to version of MediaWiki, as special pages come and go.